# Return all column names contain specific value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need help to develop a logic (SQL,SP or C#) that will return all column names that has a value specified by the user.

**For example:**

```
ID  | A       | B    | C  | D
---------------------------------------
1   | cat&dog | 10?2 | 99 | male
2   | duck    | 10&2 | 11 | female
3   | ?????   | &&&& | 0  | male&female
```

If the user enters `&`, it should return column A, B and D
If the user enters `?`, it should return column A and B

**Other important notes:**

1. I have to reuse the same code for other 80 tables, that means I cannot hard code the column name in my logic.
2. There are at least 500 columns and 10,000 rows in each table - performance is a big concern.

> > Edited: The user CAN enter more than one character. i.e. He can enter "ck" that will return column A because "duck" has "ck" in it.

Comment: You will need to use dynamic SQL for this.  Are you familiar with `sp_executesql()` (or `exec()`)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not quite...

Comment: If the user enters the digit 1, would you expect columns B and C?  Or just C?  The reason I ask is because B looks like a `(VAR)CHAR`, and C looks like an `INT`.  I think you'd need to decide how to handle "numeric" vs "string"-type data before getting too deep.

Comment: @DMason Good thing you ask. ALL of the columns are varchar except the ID. And I don't need to return anything from the ID (Primary Key) column

Comment: @DMason Sorry for the confusion part, I did not think of the data type while giving the sample data. But they are all Varchar / String

Comment: Ok, so if making this generic, the PK column for all tables can be ignored?  And columns that are not `(VAR)CHAR` can be ignored too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Test table.
CREATE TABLE guest.Test (
    ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY,
    ColA VARCHAR(32),
    ColB VARCHAR(32),
    ColC VARCHAR(32),
    ColD VARCHAR(32),

    --Non-VARCHAR cols as invalid data for testing.
    ColX INT,
    ColY DATETIME
);

--Sample data.
INSERT INTO guest.Test (ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColX, ColY)
VALUES
    ('cat&dog', '10?2', '99', 'male', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    ('duck', '10&2', '11', 'female', 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 2),
    ('?????', '&&&&', '0', 'male&female', 9, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 5);

----------------------------------------------------------------------
--Here is the template for a stored proc.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
--These first three could be your SP parameters.
DECLARE @UserInput NVARCHAR(160) = 'ck';
DECLARE @SchemaName SYSNAME = 'guest';
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME = 'Test';

DECLARE @Tsql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @Tsql = @Tsql + 'SELECT ''' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS ColumnName WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [' + c.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + c.TABLE_NAME + '] WHERE [' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''%' + @UserInput + '%'') UNION ALL '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
AND c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
--"String" data types.  Did I leave any out?
AND c.DATA_TYPE IN ('CHAR', 'NCHAR', 'VARCHAR', 'NVARCHAR')
--Exclude PRIMARY KEY column(s)
AND c.COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (
    SELECT kcu.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu
        ON kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = tc.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
    AND tc.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
);

--Remove last "UNION ALL" from string.
SET @Tsql = LEFT(@Tsql, LEN(@Tsql) - 9);

PRINT @Tsql;

--Uncomment when ready to proceed.
--EXEC (@Tsql);
```